# Flutter: How to check local file list and extract files into app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, file-management, file-manager

As we know, our mobile phone has a function that we can check files from a file list. Just like the following picture. It seems that this function's name is **filemanager**. I wondered that is it possible in Flutter to achieve a similar function, which can check my own mobile phone's files and extract one of the files into my app? What packages or ways do I need?

Thanks for your help. This question may be quite puerile, but it is my first Flutter app.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JIK0.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! It's very much possible to create a file manager with flutter.

Here's a repo to a flutter file manager
[Github](https://github.com/JideGuru/FileX)

Basically the most important package is included in dart(`dart:io`), any other package will vary on your use case.